# what's the meaning of the brackets in Property definition?

Tags: vb.net

What is the meaning of the square brackets around the name of a property in the definition ?

Example :

```
Public Property [Date] As String
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use reserved keywords as identifiers, the brackets must be used to
distinguish between the identifier and the keyword:

```
dim [String] As String

public sub [Stop]
end sub
```

On msdn it says:

> Any program element — such as a variable, class, or member — can have
>   the same name as a restricted keyword. For example, you can create a
>   variable named Loop. However, to refer to your version of it — which
>   has the same name as the restricted Loop keyword — you must either
>   qualify it by preceding it with its full namespace, or enclose it in
>   square brackets ([ ]), as in the following examples:

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwx24eb6%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

This syntax allows you to use a reserved word as the name of a member or variable. Not recommended though IMHO from a code maintainability point of view (though see comments below for an alternative point of view on this particular point)!

Particularly not recommended if you're going to declare a property called "Date" as a string, but that's a separate issue...

Comment: “Not recommended” – why? You’re right about the unfitting data type but that’s unrelated.

Comment: Yes, it's unrelated, agreed. Not recommended - because it makes your code harder for others to read and maintain, particularly if they're not as experienced with the language as you are and have to come running to somewhere like SO to ask what the syntax means...

Comment: It’s a fundamental error to try to cater to inexperienced programmers in your code. Don’t try it, it makes your code worse. I don’t buy that using reserved identifiers makes your code harder to read in principle. Maybe it shouldn’t be exaggerated but in general there’s nothing wrong with, an often a good deal speaking for, using reserved words as identifiers (case in point: `Enumerable.Select`).

Comment: I didn't say inexperienced - I'd wager that a significant percentage of experienced C# and VB developers don't know the respective syntaxes (`@int`, `[Date]`) in their languages. And I don't see how avoiding calling a property `Date` makes my code worse - I've not suggested anything other than this...

Comment: Anyway, have edited answer to make clear that this bit of it is subjective. Happy to continue discussion here, btw...

Comment: Well, if the property logically *is* a date, call it that. Say you have a class `Meeting` and you want to store its … date.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I have to agree with David M here.  In the case of a date of a meeting, a better alternative to [Date] in this instance would be MeetingDate.  Using [Date] can and will confuse matters slightly, MeetingDate (when using a class) would seem redundant, but avoids any confusion at all.  Also, if you have a date, you most likely should store it as such, there are times you wouldn't, but I think we have another discussion in that, and I'm running out of characters. ;-)

Comment: @pms1969 Having a class `Meeting` with a property `MeetingDate` is redundant und a discouraged practice. Of course one can always argue that it’s a matter of preference but the consensus is vastly on the side of avoiding the redundancy. And again the claim of confusion. **There is no confusion**. If somebody is confused by the syntax, the right course of action for them is to inform themselves (as by this question). You must not let your syntax be dictated by beginner programmers, that way lies madness.

Comment: I don't think anyone is suggesting that beginner programmers should dictate what your code looks like, but clarity of code is always prefered.  I sometimes use foreach loops when a Linq expression would work because the meaning is clearer.  Add to that, that not everyone is a super star programmer and sometimes we have to be accommodating to those that have less experience than us.  You cannot categorically say don't code for beginners, because that is all you might ever have maintaining your code in future, and better to have maintainable code than a system that no one is willing to touch.

Answer (score 3):

Date is a reserved keyword in VB.NET, but can be used as a property or variable name if enclosed in square brackets:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx